# Using group & un-group option in a shared & protected excel workbook

Tags: excel

Objective: Need to make few cells in a worksheet non-editable. So chose those cells and locked them. And then I protected the whole sheet. I had grouped cells in my worksheet. After the sheet was protected I was not able to group & un-group cells as I got error. So I wrote the below macro code which helped in grouping & un-grouping the cells in my worksheet even though it was protected.

```
Sheets("sheet-name").Unprotect Password:="password"
With Sheets("sheet-name")
.Protect Password:="password", DrawingObjects:=True,
Contents:=True, Scenarios:= True, AllowFormattingCells:=False, 
AllowFormattingColumns:=False, AllowFormattingRows:=False, userinterfaceonly:=True
.EnableOutlining=True
.EnableAutoFilter=True
End With
```

I want to allow users to enter the values in the sheet @ the same time. So I shared the workbook. But after making it as "shared" I am not able to group/un-group the cells. It is displaying the below error

"Run-time error '1004' unprotect method of worksheet class failed"

Please help me out. I am using excel 2003.

So my question is how to Group/Ungroup In A Protected Shared Workbook??

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot protect/unprotect sheets from a Shared Workbook**.

You can do it *before* sharing and thus, the cells will be protected but you cannot change this property *while* the workbook is shared.

You can try this without vba and see that it doesn't work.

You will have to find another way to deal with your grouping/ungrouping issue. Btw, did you check the options while protecting the sheet (meaningly, which option does allow / disallow grouping / ungrouping)?

Comment: There is no option for un-grouping/grouping cells available while protecting

Comment: @user933047: no there aren't but one of the protection option will allow/disallow grouping / ungrouping (maybe `Insert rows` or `Insert columns`) so you can check and find the right one.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem and got round it by using Macros to hide and unhide the rows instead of grouping and ungrouping them

Comment: please post some sample code for your answer to be more helpful